# Magento 2 How to get product collection of all products?

Tags: magento2.2, catalog, product-collection

I am trying to fetch the product collection in `Magento 2` which return the all products including

> -> with all instock and out of stock products
>
> -> with all Visibility (Not Visible Individually,Catalog,Search,Catalog, Search)
>
> -> with all status (Enabled,Disabled)

Is it possible to get this type of product collection?

Comment: where do you want to show this collection?

Answer (score 6):

Using bellow code, you fetch the product which is currently enable.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

class Yourblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   
    /*Product collection variable*/ 
    protected $_productCollection;

    protected $stockFilter;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockFilter,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollection= $productCollection;
        $this->stockFilter = $stockFilter;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getProductCollection()
    {

        $collection = $this->_productCollection->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

        // ADD THIS CODE IF YOU WANT IN-STOCK-PRODUCT
        $this->stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

**NOTE** You need to change `getProductCollection()` function code for your other requirement.

Comment: Sorry Dhiren, I have checked it already. I just trying to apply all filters in single collection.

Comment: you need to add $collection->addAttributeToFilter in same code if you want some more filter with this.

Comment: For instock/outstock in same collection?

Comment: you can add "addAttributeToFilter" as many as you want in same collection logic. And if my answer help you, you can accept so it will help other in community.

Comment: Please let me know how to use addAttributeToFilter for instock and out of stock products in same collection?

Comment: I update my answer please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73292/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-suman-singh).

Comment: $this->stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
only fetch IN-STOCK-PRODUCTs. I need instock and out of stock products in same collection at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740555/how-to-get-model-and-product-collection-in-magento-2/35679085#35679085

But here's an example anyway:

```
<?php 

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class ProductCollectionExample
{   
    /** 
     * Product collection
     *   
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */  
    protected $collection;

    /** 
     * Construct
     *   
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */  
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    ) { 
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }   

    public function doStuff()
    {   
        foreach($this->collection as $product) {
            // do stuff
        }   
    }   
}
```

Another option is that you can use the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` and leverage the `getItems()` method.

It's a bit more complicated IMHO, but it basically abstracts collections another level higher (little bit of a over simplification).

Take a look at this article by Alan Storm: https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/

Comment: don not want to use the loops to manipulate collection. Is it possible with single collection and filters?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "single collection and filters?"

You can use either `addAttributeToFilter()` if it's an EAV model, or `addFieldToFilter()` otherwise.

I believe by default, it emulates a `SELECT *` so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

You could load it into an array also with `$collection->toArray()`. Is that what you mean by single collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your collection in listing page. then add below code in `List.phtml` file

> app/design/frontend/your_vendor/your_theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()

 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

 ->load();
```